# T-SQL Query to check for duplicates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

**Locations**

```
LocationID  LocationName
=========================
1           Boston
2           Milwaukee
3           Denver
4           Denver
5           Cleveland
6           Cleveland
```

**LocationOwner**

```
LocationID  AppSecurityUserID
================================================
1           A713E156-FEAB-474C-A078-04C8022A387C
2           AF6EEFCE-7F5D-4B3C-BE3D-085A4C85832E
3           9964FAF7-8A2E-4BFE-9FE2-0B47E585FB9C
3           6F410CB4-312C-440A-8669-2106C49517F1
3           EC8CAD4A-4FB2-4BE1-97AC-28C8CF68CCE0
5           7B55B6A2-F94D-4608-938A-4206FE1DAF6D
```

The **Locations** table has mistakenly been populated with duplicate locations name, but with unique **LocationID**. I need to join the **Locations** table with the **LocationOwner** table to check that a user is not an owner for both locations. For example, a **LocationOwner** of Denver should be tied to **LocationID** of 3 *OR* 4, but not both. Basically I need to check that there are no users tied to more than one duplicate location. I'm guessing there's a query for this, but I'm not making much progress.

Answer (score 0):

You only need the first table to check for duplicates

```
WITH CTE as
(SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LocationName ORDER BY LocationID) as rn
FROM Locations)
SELECT LocationID,LocationName FROM CTE WHERE rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the two tables on LocationID and look for rows that duplicate both User and LocationName.

There are tons of questions on here already that show you how to find duplicates over multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is already a key preventing a duplicate by LocationID...

```
select * from (
    select
        o.AppSecurityUserID,
        l.LocationName,
        l.LocationID,
        LocationDupedCount = count(*) over(partition by o.AppSecurityUserID, l.LocationName)
    from
        LocationOwner o
        inner join Location l on l.LocationID = o.LocationId
) t
where
    t.LocationDupedCount > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the dupes by using GROUP BY with HAVING..

```
SELECT  lo.AppSecurityUserID,
        l.LocationName
FROM    LocationOwner lo
        JOIN Locations l ON lo.LocationID = l.LocationID
GROUP BY lo.AppSecurityUserID,
        l.LocationName
HAVING  COUNT(LocationName) > 1
```